# Extract values from nested data frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested, jsonlite

I am having this list in R, formed by three elements:

```
df <- structure(list(`[{"code":"B1182","description":"Tire pressure monitor module","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Tire pressure monitor module","description_fre":"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus","description_ger":"Reifendrucküberwachung","description_spa":"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos","description_ita":"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico","description_tur":"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü"},{"code":"B124D","description":"Sensor, tyre pressure","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Sensor, tyre pressure","description_fre":"Capteur, pression des pneus","description_ger":"Sensor Reifendruck","description_spa":"Sensor de presión del neumático","description_ita":"Sensore, pressione pneumatici","description_tur":"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı"}]` = c("B1182", 
"B124D"), `[{"code":"B1182","description":"Tire pressure monitor module","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Tire pressure monitor module","description_fre":"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus","description_ger":"Reifendrucküberwachung","description_spa":"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos","description_ita":"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico","description_tur":"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü"},{"code":"B124D","description":"Sensor, tyre pressure","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Sensor, tyre pressure","description_fre":"Capteur, pression des pneus","description_ger":"Sensor Reifendruck","description_spa":"Sensor de presión del neumático","description_ita":"Sensore, pressione pneumatici","description_tur":"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı"}]` = c("B1182", 
"B124D"), `[{"code":"B1182","description":"Tire pressure monitor module","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Tire pressure monitor module","description_fre":"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus","description_ger":"Reifendrucküberwachung","description_spa":"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos","description_ita":"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico","description_tur":"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü"},{"code":"B124D","description":"Sensor, tyre pressure","faultInformations":[{"description":"---"},{"description":"TRUE","description_eng":"TRUE","description_fre":"TRUE","description_ger":"TRUE","description_spa":"TRUE","description_ita":"TRUE","description_tur":"TRUE"}],"freezeFrames":[],"enhancedDtcInfos":[],"status":"ACTIVE","system":"MULTIFUNCTION","systemMeta":{"systemName":null,"subSystemName":null},"description_eng":"Sensor, tyre pressure","description_fre":"Capteur, pression des pneus","description_ger":"Sensor Reifendruck","description_spa":"Sensor de presión del neumático","description_ita":"Sensore, pressione pneumatici","description_tur":"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı"}]` = c("B1182", 
"B124D")), .Names = c("[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"description_fre\":\"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Reifendrucküberwachung\",\"description_spa\":\"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos\",\"description_ita\":\"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico\",\"description_tur\":\"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü\"},{\"code\":\"B124D\",\"description\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"description_fre\":\"Capteur, pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Sensor Reifendruck\",\"description_spa\":\"Sensor de presión del neumático\",\"description_ita\":\"Sensore, pressione pneumatici\",\"description_tur\":\"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı\"}]", 
"[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"description_fre\":\"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Reifendrucküberwachung\",\"description_spa\":\"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos\",\"description_ita\":\"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico\",\"description_tur\":\"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü\"},{\"code\":\"B124D\",\"description\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"description_fre\":\"Capteur, pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Sensor Reifendruck\",\"description_spa\":\"Sensor de presión del neumático\",\"description_ita\":\"Sensore, pressione pneumatici\",\"description_tur\":\"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı\"}]", 
"[{\"code\":\"B1182\",\"description\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Tire pressure monitor module\",\"description_fre\":\"Module de surveillance de la pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Reifendrucküberwachung\",\"description_spa\":\"Módulo de control de la presión de los neumáticos\",\"description_ita\":\"Modulo monitor di pressione pneumatico\",\"description_tur\":\"Lastik basıncı izleme modülü\"},{\"code\":\"B124D\",\"description\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"faultInformations\":[{\"description\":\"---\"},{\"description\":\"TRUE\",\"description_eng\":\"TRUE\",\"description_fre\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ger\":\"TRUE\",\"description_spa\":\"TRUE\",\"description_ita\":\"TRUE\",\"description_tur\":\"TRUE\"}],\"freezeFrames\":[],\"enhancedDtcInfos\":[],\"status\":\"ACTIVE\",\"system\":\"MULTIFUNCTION\",\"systemMeta\":{\"systemName\":null,\"subSystemName\":null},\"description_eng\":\"Sensor, tyre pressure\",\"description_fre\":\"Capteur, pression des pneus\",\"description_ger\":\"Sensor Reifendruck\",\"description_spa\":\"Sensor de presión del neumático\",\"description_ita\":\"Sensore, pressione pneumatici\",\"description_tur\":\"Sensör, lastik hava basıncı\"}]"
))
```

When I `print(df)` I see:

```
$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D"

$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D"

$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D"
```

You can observe that it is a nested [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) and list that comes from extracting a [json](/questions/tagged/json) field with [jsonlite](/questions/tagged/jsonlite).

Anyway, **I would like to transform this result in a dataframe formed by three rows. Furthermore, I would like to remove all extra info and keep exclusively the previous codes. How can I do it?**

Appreciate your help.

### EDIT

My original `df` contains more than 2000 elements in the list. Not all of these elements have two values, some of them don't have any, and others have more than two.

Imagine I print six elements (instead of three as before) with this output:

```
$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D"

$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D"

$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D"

$`[]`
NULL

$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D" "B365A"

$...
[1] "B1182" "B124D"
```

Here is the code, obtained after running `dput()` for the first twenty elements of the list:

```
df <- list(c("B1182", "B124D"), c("B1182", "B124D"), c("B1182", "B124D"
), c("B1182", "B124D"), c("B1182", "B124D"), c("B1182", "B124D"
), c("B1182", "B124D"), c("B1182", "B124D"), NULL, NULL, c("B1182", 
"B124D"), c("B1182", "B124D"), c("B1182", "B124D"), NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, c("P2000", "P2000", "U3003", "P2000"), c("P2000", 
    "P2000", "U3003", "P2000"), NULL)
```

How could we proceed in this more complicated case?

Comment: In which way? I properly copied/pasted the example.

Comment: Running your `df <- structure(...)` call gives a whole bunch of errors.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with unescaped characters.

Comment: I am going to try to get them again

Comment: I have just pasted the code. I tested it before copying and it worked for me.

Comment: Could be a possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the names are huge we can remove the names, then replace the `NULL` elements with `NA` and row bind the data.

```
names(df) <- NULL
df[sapply(df, is.null)] <- NA
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(df, function(x) 
         as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

#      V1    V2    V3    V4
#1  B1182 B124D  <NA>  <NA>
#2  B1182 B124D  <NA>  <NA>
#3  B1182 B124D  <NA>  <NA>
#4  B1182 B124D  <NA>  <NA>
#5  B1182 B124D  <NA>  <NA>
#6  B1182 B124D  <NA>  <NA>
#...
```

Comment: In my original df I haver more than 2000 elements in the list. Some of these elemtents contain more than two values and others don't have any. I realized that those with none values, are omitted when `do.call`, and when there are more than two, it throws an error. Could you please edit the code to implement these features?

Comment: I edited my question adding a more complicated case (which is closer to my original df). Hope this helps

Comment: @antecessor Can you add data using `dput` ?

Comment: I am getting a lot of troubles, as the names exceed 10000 bytes when dputting it...

Comment: if you don't need the names then you can remove it. Do `names(df) <- NULL`

Comment: I added a link in the Edit section

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work gives `Error: variable names are limited to 10000 bytes`.

Comment: Let me keep trying with what you said

Comment: I ran `names(df) <- NULL` and now it is amazingly simple. I added the info of the first twenty elements of the list @ronak-shah

Comment: That's great. Do you want to change those `NULL` elements to `NA` or remove those all together.

Comment: I would like to keep those as `NA`

Comment: ok, one closing bracket is missing at the end. I am going to check it and keep you posted

Comment: That was fantastic, it worked! But remember to correct the missing bracket in case sb read this question later in time!